# Order of execution in using Handler

Tags: android

When I run this, Toast 1 show first and then Toast 2:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Toast 2
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Toast_2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    // Toast_1
    Toast.makeText(this, "Toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I know that Runnable Object is pushed to MessageQueue, but when does Looper execute it in Main Thread? And why does Toast_1 come first ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method hasn't finished executing, so the Handler needs to wait until it has before it can post your Runnable.

The Looper executes it as soon as it can, but that can't be while your method is still executing. Once Toast 1 runs, `onCreate()` has finished executing, and the Handler has availability to execute that Runnable.

Comment: Thank you :), but I think when handler.post(Runnable) executes, it pushes Runnable Object to MessageQueue immediately. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Hope notice the name of that class, and how it includes the word "queue." Even if it's the first in that queue, you can't possibly have two operations running at once on a single thread.